# validate active directory user when offline

Tags: c#, .net, security, active-directory

I am looking for the best way to validate an AD user when offline. Currently our application will always be running, so windows will always have the same logged in user but many people will login to the application. When they login to the application we check the AD server if their username/password is valid and that they belong to the correct AD group.

If the network is down, what is the best practice for determining if the user is a valid AD user and belongs to the correct group? I was thinking of saving locally the last successful AD username/password then validating against that, but I hate the idea of storing passwords and being responsible for them. Thanks for any suggestions

update to possible duplicate question.

In the local cache does it save the groups that user belongs to? Also, I am not sure this local cache gets updated in our scenario. Only 1 user will ever be logged in under windows. Our application is running all the time, when a new users enter a username/password into our application we query the AD server to see if this is a valid user. At this point, does windows really save this new user into its local cache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .Net to authenticate against Active Directory when disconnected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380601/using-net-to-authenticate-against-active-directory-when-disconnected)

Comment: In the local cache does it save the groups that user belongs to? Also, I am not sure this local cache gets updated in our scenario. Only 1 user will ever be logged in under windows. Our application is running all the time, when a new users enter a username/password into our application we query the AD server to see if this is a valid user. At this point, does windows really save this new user into its local cache?